# full email size less than email header size in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2016, headers

I set my outlook to download only headers for some folders. I checked and only headers are getting downloaded. Strangely, when I tried to download full email, the size of email got reduced. For instance, one email when in the begining only header was downloaded, it is 110 KB. But when I downloaded full mail, its space shrank to 99 KB.

I am not sure what is happening in background of outlook.
Does downloading only headers save internet data and disk space?
Or is the outlook displaying the size on server of the email and on disk it might be smaller? If so, how can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research but cannot find any official documents explaining this issue. I also did some tests in my Outlook 365 but it seems to be strange that whatever I choose to Download header or Download full items, the size of the email are consistent.

I found some Official description about Download only headers, for your reference, [Managing Outlook behavior for slow connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/deployment/cached-exchange-mode#managing-outlook-behavior-for-slow-connections).